# NLTK FreqDist: get the total frequency count with the padding in a set

Tags: nlp, nltk

As a newbie in NLP, I've built a bigram frequency list by using FreqDist built-in function. Although there are frequency counts of a set of alphabets, I want to get the count with a starting padding to calculate the probability.

Since there's no unigram count for `<s>`. Is there any built-in function that I can use to count the frequency that the first letter of a set with `<s>`?

For example, I have a list of alphabet-pair with counts:`[(('<s>','n'),100),(('<s>','a'),100)]`. The total count of `'<s>'` would be 2.

My goal is to calculate the probability that equals to `count(('<s>','n'))/count('<s>')`, which equals to 1/2.

```
from nltk.util import ngrams, pad_sequence
from collections import Counter

bigram_total_word = FreqDist()

for word in training_set:
    word_with_padding = pad_sequence(word, 2, pad_left = True, left_pad_symbol='<s>')
    bigram = ngrams(word_with_padding,n=2)
    bigram_total_word = bigram_total_word + FreqDist(list(bigram))

print(bigram_total_word.most_common(30))
[(('i', 'n'), 6692), (('e', 'r'), 5676), (('e', 's'), 4528), (('e', 'd'), 4415), (('<s>', 's'), 4371), (('t', 'i'), 4357), (('o', 'n'), 4346), (('r', 'e'), 4181), (('t', 'e'), 3941), (('n', 'g'), 3847), (('<s>', 'c'), 3729), (('e', 'n'), 3659), (('a', 't'), 3586), (('a', 'n'), 3523), (('s', 't'), 3213), (('l', 'e'), 3207), (('<s>', 'p'), 2995), (('a', 'l'), 2949), (('a', 'r'), 2909), (('r', 'a'), 2870), (('r', 'i'), 2781), (('n', 't'), 2751), (('o', 'r'), 2589), (('l', 'i'), 2576), (('<s>', 'a'), 2521), (('i', 's'), 2521), (('<s>', 'b'), 2387), (('d', 'e'), 2369), (('<s>', 'd'), 2337), (('c', 'o'), 2290)]
```

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by `count the frequency that the first letter of a set with <s>`. Could you share an example of what output you expect ?

Comment: Thanks for replying, I've added an example.

Comment: You can use a list comprehension like this : `len([ngram for ngram, count in bigram_total_word.most_common(30) if '<s>' in ngram])`. This will count the number of ngram that contain '<s>'.

Comment: @ygorg thank you for the list comprehension solution! I never thought about it before. Have a nice day.